# Server randomly shutsdown and blows fan at full speed with no video output

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, gpu

## Specs

- **Model:** HP Z230
- **CPU:** Intel Xeon e3 1230 v3
- **RAM:** 1x8GB DDR3 Non-ECC RAM
- **GPU:** Radeon HD 8570
- **NIC:** Intel 82571 Dual Port NIC
- **Storage:** 1x128GB SATA SSD, 1X1TB 7.2k RPM HDD

## The problem

It randomly shuts down and starts blowing fans at full speed. When it's in the phase of blowing the fans at full speed,
there is no video output and probably no operating system (I can't ssh or basically use any service). Sometimes it fixes
by itself and restarts normally.

## How the problem started

The server had been running for 7 days straight until now, that's when I decided to shut it down to install more ram.
This is point after which the problems started to begin.

### Installing ECC

I removed the existing 1x8GB DDR3 RAM and replaced it with 2x8GB registered ECC memory, only to realise that this system
only supports unbuffered ECC. When I tried to boot the system with registered ECC memory, the fans blew at full speed
and no video output was there.

### Removing ECC

So I removed the ECC memory and replaced it with original stick and also added 3x8GB DDR3 Non-ECC RAM, bringing the
total up to 32 GB.

### Back to square one

I then removed all ram except for the original stick, the problem still remains.

## What I've tried

- Ran HP's built-in memory check on all 4 sticks, passed.
- Reseated everything on the board.
- Reapplied thermal paste on GPU and CPU.
- Switched from linux to BSD, thinking it could be a problem in the kernel itself.
- checked the system logs, even tried kdump
- tried connecting the psu directly to different main outlets rather than a UPS
- changed the power cord
- changed the PSU
- switched to different SATA ports.
- crying :(

Comment: Id try running memtest86 over an extended period of time. This sounds like bad RAM to me. I wonder if it cpuld be a mismatch between the old and new RAM in a dyal channel config?  (Im not an expert here though)

Comment: Also, I wonder if this would find a better audience at serverfault.com?

Comment: Okay I'll run memtest86. Doesn't serverfault request to not ask questions related to home use?

Comment: Also if it were to be a problem with ram, shouldn't it have been fixed when I switched back to the original single stick that had been working for weeks non-stop?

Comment: If you can guarantee If you did not damage the stick due to static or physical force, and no dust got into the slot and you put it in the same slot and the power was definitely off, maybe.   The case remains though - The server is rebooting (which is causing the fans to go full tilt).   It is very common for computers not to show anything on the screen when there are memory related issues.   Thought - when the screen is blank, does it make any beeps - these are often a hint as to what the problem is - eg - https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_1997210-1528385-16

Comment: There are no beeps (the speaker does work) and no red lights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced the system but kept the same CPU and RAM, turns out there was a tiny bit of thermal paste on the bottom side of the CPU. I'm not sure if it had been there all along or it was applied during replacement but the system has been working fine since. It could have also been a faulty motherboard.